# Filterby multiple varying values in excel pivot table, without manually selecting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

So I have a database connection that pulls data into a pivot table in excel, however I have a column called "Customer" I want to filter on, but i want to filter on specific customers (i want to filter on around 100 different customers), so this would be tedious to go though the filter on the pivot customer column and select each one, one by one. I was wondering is there a way to filter the "Customer" column in the pivot table by multiple values, e.g. if I had a another table with a list of all the customers I need, can i use that table to somehow connect to the pivot and filter the pivot by only the customer in my other table?

Comment: One thought is adding another column to your data. That column could be a yes/no and link to the data you want to filter on.

Comment: @Isolated I think i kinda of understand what you mean, but can you please explain in a bit more detail

Comment: This can be done in the database connection, but it probably requires a rebuild of the connection (to accept variables) and the pivot table.

Comment: @MathewsJoy I missed your comment about the database connection. Not sure how to accomplish if that's the case.